# I've got 404, then rebuilt project. Now it's working, but my mind don't (Java, Spring MVC, Tomcat 10)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat10

I'm writing a simple messenger (or trying at least) on Java 21, Spring 6.0.13, Tomcat 10.1.16.
Getting 404 error on deploy every time and have zero ideas what's wrong.

**UPD:**
Well, for some reason, completely same project written from zero works absolutely fine, guess something went wrong after i deleted it and got back from git hub repo. It is working now, but i still got question - what was that? And how to fix this without making same programm again? It is a small project for learning, so not a big deal, but imagine doing this on actual app? Need an answer, thanks in advance.

**Git Hub repository** - *https://github.com/anxidy/Messenger*

My **pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>6.0.13</spring.version>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.3.0.FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.224</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.security.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.security.enterprise-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns = "https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
         version = "6.0">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>ru.anxidy.web.AppConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class MainPageController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "mainPage";
    }
}
```

and **Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/pages/",".jsp").viewClass(JstlView.class);
    }
}
```

"mainPage" is a jsp in pages folder.

Deploying this on Tomcat returns a 404 page, no logs, no other errors, nothing. I don't understand what i'm missing. I've reinstalled Tomcat several times, re-made artifact and facet too. Please, help me out.

Comment: Where is your `/pages` folder located?

Comment: @M.Deinum src/main/web

Comment: Which is a weird place (unless it is `src/main/webapp`?

Comment: @M.Deinum no, just web. Should it be somewhere else? I followed an example with same structure

Comment: Maven default structure uses `src/main/webapp` so will ignore what you have now unless you have some additional setup. You also don't need `.viewClass(JstlView.class)` that is detected automatically.

Comment: @M.Deinum changing that did not help, unfortunately.

Comment: Well with the limited information you provided that is all that we can do. We don't see an error message or log from Tomcat, we don't see the full overview of your build file nor your project structure. I would also suggest to use Spring Boot instead of plain Spring, that will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @M.Deinum the main problem is there no error message in logs, idea tells that everything is working fine, although it's not. I can add a link to gh repository, no problem. Also I'll take your note about Spring Boot, seems like a good idea.